# Comparing two object arraylists

Tags: java

First time here so I hope this makes sense!

I have two object arrays say  l1 and  l2, I want to run a compare between these two lists and get a the unmatched value in say in  l3. 
User class contains 2 Strings:

```
userEnteredValue 
valueReturnedFromDatabase
```

Say, l1 contains: Java, JSF, JAXR, foo
l2 contains: JSF, JAXR

I could run a compare for matching values, but for not for non-matching values. The logic seems to be flawed. Any help?

For matching values:

```
for(User u1 : l1) {
   for(User u2: l2) { 
      if(u1.getUserEnteredValue().equals(u2.getValueReturnedFromDatabase())) {
        l3.add(u1);
      }
}
```

But, for the non-matching when I say not equal to, instead of getting only the unique values I get all values. 
A couple of similar posts on Stackoverflow suggest to implement the equals and hashcode method in the User class. Is this necessary, since my arraylist size don't go beyond 5 to 10.

Comment: Can't you use 2 HashSets for this and find the overlapping parts using that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
for(User u1 : l1) {
    boolean unique = true;
    for(User u2: l2) { 
        if(u1.getUserEnteredValue().equals(u2.getValueReturnedFromDatabase())) {
            unique = false;
            break;
        }
    } 
    if(unique){
        l3.add(u1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers! I used this snippet, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `contains()` method from `java.util.ArrayList` to determine whether your list contains the object.

Example:

```
for(User u1:l1) {
    if(!l2.contains(u1)) {
        l3.add(u1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `l2.contains(u1)` is not the same as `u1.getUserEnteredValue().equals(u2.getValueReturnedFromDatabase())` he will need to override `equals` and `hashCode` in the `User` class in order for that to be true.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Iterate through one array and check if it "contains()" the element from other array, using the above method provided with ArrayList in java.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Java 8 and you would like some shorter format:

```
 List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
 List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("b");

 List<String> l3 = l1.stream().filter(e -> !l2.contains(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's make your problem even smaller.
I have 2 arrays
l1 = [1, 2]
l2 = [2, 3]

```
for(int i : l1) {
    for(int j : l2) {
        if(i != j) {
            l3.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's examine this code.
When `i = 1`, `j = 2` then `i != j` i.e. `1 != 2` is true and 1 will be inserted in l3.
When `i = 1`, `j = 3` then `i != j` i.e. `1 != 3` is true and 1 again will be inserted in l3.
When `i = 2`, `j = 2` then `i != j` i.e. `2 != 2` is false
When `i = 2`, `j = 3` then `i != j` i.e. `1 != 2` is true and 2 will be inserted in l3.
So the final array will be l3 = [1, 2] (*if it is a set. or [1, 1, 2] if it is a list*) i.e. all the elements of l1 will be inserted in l2.

To get unique elements of l1 you will have to check all elements of l2 for same element in l1 1 by 1 and if it is not found in complete l2 then add it in l3.

```
rootloop:
for(int i : l1) {
    for(int j : l2) {
        if(i == j) {
            continue rootloop;
        }
        l3.add(i);
    }
}
```

Now change the above code to work for your problem.

But these kind of searching are so common that their implementation is already given in collection framework.

```
for(int i : l1) {
    if(!l2.contains(i)){
        l3.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It would have good if I had put a couple of console messages and traced the snippet. Hope this would help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

One could use the Array of matching entities for the creation of unmatched entities as follows:

```
User[] matchingUsers = ...
User[] AllUsers = ...

List<User> listOfMatchingUsers = Arrays.asList(matchingUsers);
List<User> listOfAllUsers = Arrays.asList(allUsers);

List<User> unmatchedUsers = listOfAllUsers.removeAll(listOfMatchingUsers);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see many answers using list.contains, i do not agree as contains use direct loop so the performance will be an issue for large lists O(n^2).

Instead you can use maps, add each list to a map with key and value the same then do the following:

```
Iterator it = map1.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    if(map2.get(pair.getValue())!=null) {
            list3.add(map2.get(pair.getValue()));
     }
}
```